# Allow cross origin application side (no control of API)

Tags: nginx, cross-domain, nginx-location

I have an application which should be able to read in data from any data source, meaning any API from any domain.

How to get around the Cross-Origin problem when you don't have any control over the API or even the domain it is coming from?

I know that you could simulate the same domain by adding a

```
location /data/ {

    proxy_pass http://exampleAPIdomain.com/data/;

}
```

block to allow for a specific API domain (here: exampleAPIdomain.com), but in my case I want to be open for any domain.

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible by using a variable in the `proxy_pass`-directive:

```
proxy_pass $somevariable$request_uri;
```

You can set the actual host via a header for example, then the directive would be:

```
proxy_pass $http_someheader$request_uri;
```

**Security note: If you expose this to the internet without some form of authorization, then everybody can use your proxy to proxy anything.**